# C++ Debug Window showing "<incomplete type> for string variable

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, clion, incomplete-type

To my knowledge I'm initializing a string a fairly normal way and when I debug, the variables window in my IDE (CLion) shows its value as `<incomplete type>`.  I have some simple code that results in the issue for the string variable `Bob`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string Bob = "this doesn't show up in the variables window";
    std::cout << Bob << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what impact it has but I'll include the CMakeLists file that appears to be the simplest that I can use.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(testing123)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11"}

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testing123 ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/clang++")
```

I looked at the other questions and they all had to do with classes and pointers which I can't see to be directly related, so if they are to blame for this, I'd appreciate an explanation as to how that would be.

Comment: We cannot try compiling the above, because (for starters) we do not have the various #include files. Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable program.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've posted something that replicates the problem without the excess.

Comment: `#include <string>` ?

Comment: Unfortunately `#include <string>` appears to have no effect, Matt

Answer (score 23):

You might need to set [debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/debug_mode_using.html) using `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` [macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html).

You can do this in a CMakeLists.txt file with the following line:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG")`

Answer (score 3):

### Using a standard library with debug symbols

On Linux, a less intrusive way than to recompile your whole source code with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` is to define

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
```

for your debugger or IDE. You may have to install it via

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6-8-dbg
```

first. On Ubuntu, where I get CLion via Snap, I then replaced the symlink at `/snap/bin/clion` with a file that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/bin/snap run clion "$@"
```

Now I can see the contents of strings, at least in LLDB (I didn't try GDB).

### Hack

For GDB, a very quick workaround without any preparation is to cast a string to `char*`:

```
(gdb) p (char*) my_string
$13 = 0x2058970 "These are the contents"
```

This also works in CLion out of the box.